# VB6 Memory Leak

Tags: vb6, memory-management, memory-leaks

Can a VB6 program that does not contain the keyword 'New' have memory leaks?

If so, please provide an example.

Comment: The question is a bit poorly worded. I'm assuming you mean "Is it possible to have memory leaks in VB6 when you are not using objects. That is, are there causes other than the well-known circular reference problem with objects". Bob doesn't understand what you mean. Can you reword the question?

Answer (score 4):

To summarise the answers so far: calling another component might introduce memory leaks. The component could be buggy, or you might be misusing it. The component could be an OCX or a DLL (including API calls into a Windows DLL, which is an excellent way to leak memory and windows resources not to mention lots of other thrilling problems).

And a pedantic point: you can create objects using `CreateObject`, so you could leak memory through [circular references](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/Code/Techniques/Dealing_with_Circular_References/article.asp) without using `New`. And [onedaywhen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15354/onedaywhen) has pointed out in the comments you can also create circular references with form variables without using `New`. But I think the point of the question was whether VB6 memory leaks can have other causes besides circular references.

---

Recursive's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674247/vb6-memory-leak/674270#674270) does not cause a memory leak - reference counting will tidy up the memory on each execution of the loop - see my comment on the answer.

Comment: Another pendantic point: you can create circular references using VB.Form instances, which can be loaded without using the New keyword.

Answer (score 3):

You could be calling a third party DLL that has memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it could.  Before I learned about a memory leak in a specific Windows API call, a VB6 program I wrote that used Transparent Blits exhibited a memory leak.  So, while the leak wasn't in the program itself, it was in one of the functions that VB6 called in the Win32 API.

Answer (score 1):

... and don't forget memory leaks in OCXs

Answer (score 0):

We had a leak using global variables in a module while running under COM+. This was a long time ago don't remember the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

What is this obsession with New in regard to memory leaks?  I don't see any relationship aside from allocating another object by touching the reference variable after setting it to Nothing.

If you do this you probably have a logic error anyway.  Not using New just means you blow up instead, hardly my idea of "fixing" anything.

The worst leaks might involve API calls like those to OLE or GDI routines that require explicit cleanup/deallocation of implicitly allocated data structures.

But as I said, associating New with memory leaks sounds nuts to me.

Comment: I think the question is a bit poorly worded. I think it means "are there causes for memory leaks in VB6 when you are not using objects, i.e. besides the well-known circular reference problem with objects".